# RestSharp RestRequest.AddBody not using Newton.Json attributes

Tags: c#, restsharp

```
var obj = new MyObject();
```

I am having an issue getting RestSharp `RestRequest.AddBody(obj)`; to serialize the object correctly.

```
class MyObject
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName="a")]
   public A{get;set;}

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName="b")]
   public B{get;set;}
}
```

problem is the AddBody serializer is not taking into account my JsonProperty attributes and I can seem to figure out how to set the serializer on the RestRequest or the RestClient?

Comment: Have you found a way to set this globally, and not per request?

Comment: The same approach will work if implemented against the client rather than individual request, but in my case I didn't want the behavior to cascade through all requests, just particular instances that required one-off projection between repository object configuration and the API's version of the object.

Comment: Which method/property do you set on the client to achieve that? I know I can use `AddHandler` to add a default `deserializer`, but I can't find out how to add a default `serializer`

Comment: @NilsH Did you ever figure out how to set this globally on the client? I can only see how to do it on the request via `request.JsonSerializer = new MyCustomSerializer();`

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp.Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used an answer of tafaju and implemented my serializer for json like this.

```
public class CustomJsonSerializer : ISerializer
{
    public CustomJsonSerializer()
    {
        ContentType = "application/json";
    }

    public string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }

    public string RootElement { get; set; }

    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public string DateFormat { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

}
```

And it works perfectly for me, it reads attributes and serializes all types correctly. But I didn't test it with all types.
Documentation says that RootElement, Namespace, DateFormat aren't used for json.

Answer (score 5):

I found following link which resolved the issue of a lack of attribute support [RestSharp Deserialization](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization)

Overriding the default serializers

When making requests with XML or JSON request bodies, you can specify your own implementation of ISerializer to use.

```
var request = new RestRequest();
request.RequestFormat = RequestFormat.Xml;
request.XmlSerializer = new SuperXmlSerializer(); // implements ISerializer
request.AddBody(person); // object serialized to XML using your custom serializer;
```

And implemented the following class to override the default JsonSerializer [New Json Serializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestClient.cs)